# UITableViewCell Puzzle?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I'm using the TableView and use the tableViewCell property for dispalying the image in the cell

```
cell.imageView.image = aNewsInfo.smallImageData;
```

but it shows the same image size which we get by the parser because of the different size of images i want to set the size this image frame in the cell to display all the images with same alignment. For this is also try this

`cell.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30);

    cell.imageView.image = aNewsInfo.smallImageData;`

but it won't work .Plz suggest the best way for solving this one...

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
cell.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
```

From Apple [UIView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/contentMode)  Documentation.

> UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit:
>
> Scales the content to fit the size of
>   the view. This option maintains the
>   aspect ratio of the content. Any
>   remaining area of the view’s bounds is
>   transparent.

Answer (score 0):

```
UIImageView *myImageView;
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {

if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier]) {
[self.contentView addSubview:myImageView];
}
- (void)layoutSubviews {
frame= CGRectMake(0 ,0, 50, 50);

myImageView.frame = frame;
}
```

//  in cell for row at indexpath

```
cell.myImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"calendar_color.png"];
```

stolen from [here](http://blog.webscale.co.in/?p=284)